# When try to export APK of project using Mapbox SDK in Unity, it crashed IL2CPP error

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am trying to export my project as 64bit with IL2CPP on Unity. But it gives an error like ;

```
Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!.
```

I created a new project on Unity and when I tried to export with IL2CPP, it worked perfectly. Then, I imported Mapbox SDK again to the new project, it crashed again. I guess the problem in Mapbox.

The error is here:

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="D:\Projects\deneme2\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="D:/android-ndk-r16b" --map-file-parser="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.7f1\Editor\Data\Tools\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe" --directory="D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --generatedcppdir="D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: D:\Projects\deneme2\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 653 of which compiled: 0
Total compilation time: 228 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: D:\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\CBS Lab\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp955E.tmp" -o "D:\Projects\deneme2\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_2C4240636ECA75600F9D629C330F4D32\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "D:\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "D:\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "D:\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26872: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26961: error: undefined reference to 'PauseSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27057: error: undefined reference to 'CapturePixelData'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27003: error: undefined reference to 'GetVideoTextureHandles'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27047: error: undefined reference to 'SetCameraNearFar'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27067: error: undefined reference to 'SessionAddUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27082: error: undefined reference to 'SessionRemoveUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22071: error: undefined reference to 'GetBlendShapesInfo'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22071: error: undefined reference to 'GetBlendShapesInfo'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22796: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22796: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22904: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22904: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26971: error: undefined reference to 'HitTest'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26984: error: undefined reference to 'GetLastHitTestResult'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26891: error: undefined reference to 'StartSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26740: error: undefined reference to 'unity_CreateNativeARSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26771: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetSessionCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26793: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26815: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetUserAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26837: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetFaceAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26853: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26872: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26891: error: undefined reference to 'StartSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26910: error: undefined reference to 'StartSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26929: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26948: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26961: error: undefined reference to 'PauseSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26971: error: undefined reference to 'HitTest'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26984: error: undefined reference to 'GetLastHitTestResult'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27003: error: undefined reference to 'GetVideoTextureHandles'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27014: error: undefined reference to 'GetAmbientIntensity'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27025: error: undefined reference to 'GetTrackingQuality'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27036: error: undefined reference to 'GetARPointCloud'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27047: error: undefined reference to 'SetCameraNearFar'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27057: error: undefined reference to 'CapturePixelData'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27067: error: undefined reference to 'SessionAddUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27082: error: undefined reference to 'SessionRemoveUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26740: error: undefined reference to 'unity_CreateNativeARSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27036: error: undefined reference to 'GetARPointCloud'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26853: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26910: error: undefined reference to 'StartSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26948: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26929: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27014: error: undefined reference to 'GetAmbientIntensity'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27025: error: undefined reference to 'GetTrackingQuality'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22796: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22904: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: D:\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\CBS Lab\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp955E.tmp" -o "D:\Projects\deneme2\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_2C4240636ECA75600F9D629C330F4D32\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "D:\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "D:\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "D:\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26872: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26961: error: undefined reference to 'PauseSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27057: error: undefined reference to 'CapturePixelData'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27003: error: undefined reference to 'GetVideoTextureHandles'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27047: error: undefined reference to 'SetCameraNearFar'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27067: error: undefined reference to 'SessionAddUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:27082: error: undefined reference to 'SessionRemoveUserAnchor'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22071: error: undefined reference to 'GetBlendShapesInfo'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22071: error: undefined reference to 'GetBlendShapesInfo'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22796: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22796: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22904: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:22904: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:23022: error: undefined reference to 'IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26971: error: undefined reference to 'HitTest'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26984: error: undefined reference to 'GetLastHitTestResult'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26891: error: undefined reference to 'StartSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26740: error: undefined reference to 'unity_CreateNativeARSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26771: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetSessionCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26793: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26815: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetUserAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26837: error: undefined reference to 'session_SetFaceAnchorCallbacks'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26853: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26872: error: undefined reference to 'StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26891: error: undefined reference to 'StartSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26910: error: undefined reference to 'StartSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26929: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSession'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26948: error: undefined reference to 'StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions'
D:\Projects\deneme2\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7.cpp:26961: error: undefined reference to 'PauseSession'
```

I couldn't any solution for this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I Delete ARKIT folder from assets folder. if you are building for android ARKIt did not Need in that situation.